# '.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, oledb

Please excuse Im new in Visual .net I want a string connection. But every time I click the login button an error appears:

> The '.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server' provider is not registered on the local machine

I get the "NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server" provider from the properties of dbTestra.mdf (Data connection that I made.)

Here is my code:

```
Dim dbProvider As String
Dim dbSource As String
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String

dbProvider = "PROVIDER=.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server;"
dbSource = "Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test\Test\dbTest.mdf"

con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
con.Open()

sql = "SELECT * FROM users"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

go to `BUILD > Configuration Manager >` then change PLATFORM to x86.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you didn't set dbProvider variable that should be like this

```
dbProvider="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```